# referential integrity constraint during runtime entries in sql server database

Tags: sql-server

Ii have two forms in which data is being added into two tables. One table has a FK which refers to the other table primary key. In the second form I insert values in to the form and want to store it in the db.

I get the following error

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_*StuDetail*_eduid__5AA469F6". The conflict occurred in database "Dunstan_DB", table "dbo.EduDetails", column 'eduid'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

How can this be resolved? How do we know during runtime that this value present in parent table as primary key or not?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, [take a look into the FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and see how to correctly ask a question. Post the query you are using for the insertion, table design and if possible some test data. That way you will have more chances of  getting an answer. You can use this tool [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) to post some working code with test data.

Answer (score 0):

Within SQL Mangement studio, there is a tool called profiler (may not be in express version) it allows you to see the exact queries that are being sent to the database. However its pretty certain that the value you are sending to the detail table does not contain the pk-fk value in the master table. You need to ensure the master table is inserted to before the detail. Break your program when you are updating / inserting the detail , and simply run the query

```
Select * from MasterTable WHERE ID = PassedFK
```